# ENABLE NOVALIDATE on unique index oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, unique-constraint, unique-index

In oracle, I want to add this unique constraint to a table with some records that contracted this unique constraint. for adding this unique constraint without validating previous data on the table I added ENABLE NOVALIDATE at the end of the statement but it has an error:

```
 ORA-02158: invalid CREATE INDEX option
```

Is there any way to add this unique index without validating previous records in Table?

```
create unique index UK_SAME_THREAD ON T_THREADPARTICIPANT
    (case when C_OPPOSITE_USER_ID is not null then C_OPPOSITE_USER_ID else null end,
     case when C_OPPOSITE_USER_ID is not null then F_PARTICIPANT else null end,
     case when C_OPPOSITE_USER_ID is not null then C_CONTACT_TYPE else null end)
    ENABLE NOVALIDATE;
```

Comment: and the error is....?

Comment: @OldProgrammer i got this error: ORA-02158: invalid CREATE INDEX option

Answer (score 1):

Workaround is to **a)** create index (non-unique), **b)** create unique constraint that doesn't validate existing values.

Table that contains duplicate ID values:

```
SQL> select * From test;

        ID
----------
         1
         1
         2
```

This is what you tried to do:

```
SQL> create unique index i1 on test (id) enable novalidate;
create unique index i1 on test (id) enable novalidate
                                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02158: invalid CREATE INDEX option
```

Let's just `alter table` and add unique constraint (that won't work either):

```
SQL> alter table test add constraint uk_id unique (id) enable novalidate;
alter table test add constraint uk_id unique (id) enable novalidate
                                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02299: cannot validate (SCOTT.UK_ID) - duplicate keys found
```

So: **create index** first ...

```
SQL> create index i1_test_id on test (id);

Index created.
```

... and **alter the table** next:

```
SQL> alter table test add constraint uk_id unique (id) enable novalidate;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Does it work?

```
SQL> insert into test (id) values (2);
insert into test (id) values (2)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.UK_ID) violated


SQL> insert into test (id) values (3);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

I guess it does.